# Is it necessary to validate a form's select element?

Tags: forms, validation

Is it really necessary to also filter or clean a form's `select element` since the input is not actually entered by the user but rather the user selects from an already entered options? 
**Note** form submission method is `POST`. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You're assuming that the user can't alter it, when in reality they can. Any DOM inspector would allow a user to simply go in and change the values of your options, or even add new options. **Always, always** validate user input on the server-side, for *everything*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I always do that but I just decided to ask to be sure I've not been fooling.